# $A\cap G=A\cap H=1$ implies $A=1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G\times H$ is an abelian group and $A\le G\times H$.

Is it true that $A\cap G=A\cap H=1$ implies $A=1$? ($1$ is the trivial subgroup)

Answer (score 3):

In general, no. Take for example $\langle (1,1) \rangle \leq \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot...

Comment: @Samandj: If you have found this answer to be helpful, don't forget to click the check underneath the up/down arrows next to the post to accept this as the answer.